# Save triples in a SPARQL remote endpoint using Jena library?

Tags: sparql, jena, semantic-web, marklogic, triples

How can Jena be used to save triples in a SPARQL endpoint?

I could use SPARQL RestFul API but I wonder if this is also doable using Jena classes.

Answer (score 4):

For SPARQL Update you can do the following:

```
UpdateRequest update = UpdateFactory.create("# Your SPARQL Updates");
UpdateProcessor processor = UpdateExecutionFactory.createRemote(update, "http://your-domain/update");
processor.execute();
```

If you are talking about the graph store protocol i.e. uploading entire graphs at once then you can use the [DatasetAccessor](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/query/DatasetAccessor.html) API e.g.

```
DatasetAccessor accessor = DatasetAccessorFactory.createHTTP("http://your-domain/ds");
accessor.putModel(m);
```

Comment: This way I need to write the SPARQL. I need something that automatically build and execute the needed SPARQL for the triples I want to insert.

Comment: @bsz That's a fairly major constraint and you should state such constraints in your question

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about MarkLogic specifically (you tagged the question with marklogic), then this github project will likely interest you:

https://github.com/marklogic/marklogic-jena

> This library integrates MarkLogic Semantics feature into the Jena RDF
>   Framework as a persistence and query layer.

Note: not officially released yet currently, but close. Might be worth a look..

HTH!